# MYSQL Procedure running but no result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created one mysql procedure, while executing the procedure - no errors. But result is not showing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc1`()

BEGIN

(SELECT 'idTienda', 'idArticulo', 'Descripcion', 'Peso', 'Precio', 'Importe' )
UNION

(SELECT idTienda, idArticulo, Descripcion, Peso, Precio, Importe

FROM dat_ticket_linea

INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/sales.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'

TERMINATED BY ';'

ESCAPED BY '"'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n');

END
```

Appreciate if any one help me to resolve it

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` writes to a file, it doesn't return a result.

Comment: Edge - while executing query it write to file, but while creating procedure it doesnt work

Comment: While creating the procedure, or while executing it?

Comment: While executing the procedure, it does not show any error. While i execute the query it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dat_ticket_linea`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dat_ticket_linea` (
    ->   `idTienda` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `idArticulo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `Descripcion` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Peso` DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Precio` DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Importe` DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `dat_ticket_linea` (
    ->   `idTienda`,
    ->   `idArticulo`,
    ->   `Descripcion`,
    ->   `Peso`,
    ->   `Precio`,
    ->   `Importe`
    -> ) VALUES (
    ->   1, 1, 'Descripcion 1', 100, 200, 300
    -> ), (
    ->   1, 2, 'Descripcion 2', 400, 500, 600
    -> ), (
    ->   2, 3, 'Descripcion 3', 700, 800, 900
    -> );
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `proc1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `proc1`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT
    ->     'idTienda',
    ->     'idArticulo',
    ->     'Descripcion',
    ->     'Peso',
    ->     'Precio',
    ->     'Importe'
    ->   UNION
    ->   SELECT
    ->     `idTienda`,
    ->     `idArticulo`,
    ->     `Descripcion`,
    ->     `Peso`,
    ->     `Precio`,
    ->     `Importe`
    ->   FROM
    ->     `dat_ticket_linea`
    ->   INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file/sales.csv'
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    ->          ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->          ESCAPED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `proc1`;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> \! sudo cat /path/to/file/sales.csv
"idTienda";"idArticulo";"Descripcion";"Peso";"Precio";"Importe"
"1";"1";"Descripcion 1";"100.00";"200.00";"300.00"
"1";"2";"Descripcion 2";"400.00";"500.00";"600.00"
"2";"3";"Descripcion 3";"700.00";"800.00";"900.00"
```